# How to apply values to multiple functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Basically, I need to do something like `map`, but instead of applying a function to all elements in a collection, I need to apply the same (set of) value(s) to a collection of functions (does this operation have a name?). This might seem like a simple question, but I haven't found an idiomatic way to do it in Clojure. For the special case where I need to apply only one value to each function, for example, I have used

```
(for [f funs] (f value))
```

where `value` is, of course, the value I need each function to take as an argument, and `funs` is the collection of functions which need to be called with `value` as the argument.

My question is, then, is there a function in Clojure that does this, but is also generalised for arbitrary numbers of arguments? Or is the above indeed idiomatic Clojure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for [`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt)

> **juxt**
>
> Takes a set of functions and returns a fn that is the juxtaposition
>   of those fns. The returned fn takes a variable number of args, and
>   returns a vector containing the result of applying each fn to the
>   args (left-to-right).
>   ((juxt a b c) x) => [(a x) (b x) (c x)]

Answer (score 9):

From [a section](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#map) of CLOJURE for the BRAVE and TRUE

> Another fun thing you can do with map is pass it a collection of
>   functions. You could use this if you wanted to perform a set of
>   calculations on different collections of numbers, like so:

```
(def sum #(reduce + %))
(def avg #(/ (sum %) (count %)))
(defn stats
  [numbers]
  (map #(% numbers) [sum count avg]))

(stats [3 4 10])
; => (17 3 17/3)

(stats [80 1 44 13 6])
; => (144 5 144/5)
```

Comment: It never occurred to me to put the "%" at the head of the list. Nice.

Comment: Great. This little example really helped me understand just that little bit more.
Thanks! I see Clojure really is a first-class language. (that's a joke and an observation)
(map #(apply % (range 1 3)) [+ - / *]); never occurred to me to put the functions in a list...